# How to check if a value in one dataframe is present in keys in the other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df_1:

```
         Letters Boolean
          a         Nan
          b         Nan
          c         Nan
```

df_2:

```
 a     b     d
 2.7   1.2   3.6
 1      2     3
```

How do I check if df_1['letters'] is present in df_2.keys(). If it is present, I want boolean to take the value 'x':
Something like:

```
     Letters Boolean
      a         x
      b         x
      c         Nan
```

I tried using this code:

```
for x in df_1['letters']:
   if x in df_2.keys():
     df_1['Boolean']='x'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1['Boolean'] = np.where(df1['Letters'].isin(df2.columns), 'x', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need :

```
df1['Boolean']=df1.Letters.isin(df2.columns).map({True:'x',False:np.nan})
print(df1)

  Letters Boolean
0       a       x
1       b       x
2       c     NaN
```